# Custom comparator hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table with column qualifier in this format- Id:timestamp and value is the actual object. I want to filter out the cells in a certain timestamp range. I see Qualifier filters as a good fit, but this would also need a custom comparator to chop off UUID part from the timestamp:UUID. Are there any examples of custom comparators available or am I even thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**You are in the right direction.**
Here is a [example](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments) related to your problem, you can test it directly.
Provide some explanation, when you want to implement a custom filter, you have to extends `FilterBase`. In this example, I directly implement a [filter](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mogujie/mst/filters/CustomFilterForRishi.java) extends `SingleColumnValueFilter` which is very simple, just add some trick to the comparator. Use this example just as a tip.